# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails while adding another foreign key

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add a foreign key constraint in my table. My table structure are:
table requisition
[image: requisition]

My next table where i want to add foreign key of requisition table

requisition_approval
[image: requisition_approval]

When i try to add a foreign key constraint with following sql query:

```
ALTER TABLE `requisition_approval` ADD  CONSTRAINT `requisition_id` FOREIGN KEY (`requisition_id`) REFERENCES `requisition`(`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

It gives following error:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`proprompt`.`#sql-34e8_3d7`, CONSTRAINT `requisition_id` FOREIGN KEY (`requisition_id`) REFERENCES `requisition` (`id`))
```

What is the problem here and how can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Error is in the requisition_approval table more specificly in the requisition_id column. You inserted id 0 which does not references any id in requisition table. Change the value to 1 and this will work :)